# How to create a code analysis rule to warn about Thread.Sleep usage

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper, code-analysis, thread-sleep

We have ended up with quite a lot of problems in our codebase, specifically unit tests, where devs have been using `Thread.Sleep` to wait for things. These turn out to be very fragile and high maintenance.

Does anyone know if there is a either a Visual Studio "Code Analysis" rule or a Resharper "Code Issue" that can detect and warn about usages of `Thread.Sleep`?

If not, what is the easiest way to create such a rule?

Answer (score 2):

OK this is incredibly easy with Resharper. See [Creating Custom Code Inspections and Quick-Fixes](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/2016.2/Code_Inspection__Creating_Custom_Inspections_and_QuickFixes.html).

Here is what my custom pattern looks like, and it's set to provide a warning message to devs to avoid `Thread.Sleep`:

[image: Resharper custom search pattern for Thread.Sleep]